# Css и column-gap

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-selectors

Друзья, добрый день. Есть верстка с использованием свойства column-gap у flex.

codepen.io/devilar/pen/jOVpqKq

Почему блоки не становятся в 5 рядочков, как и должны? Свойство box-sizing:border-box на месте, чтобы исключить все бордеры и прочие приблуды.

Все перепробовал - бесполезно.

Я конечно могу накостылять и изменить длину внутренних блоков:

width: calc(100%/5 - 5px);

Но подразумеваю что это бред и так работать не должно.

Мало того, в этом случае если накостылять, если присмотреться, блоки не занимают всей ширины родителя. С краю остается несколько пикселей: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX8vb.jpg

Выручайте, братцы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю вы хотите так.

```css
.dv-valute-changer-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dv-valute-changer-container>div {
    background: silver;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="dv-valute-changer-container"><div class="">GBP</div><div class="">HKD</div><div class="">IDR</div><div class="">ILS</div><div class="">DKK</div><div class="">INR</div><div class="">CHF</div><div class="">MXN</div><div class="">CZK</div><div class="">SGD</div><div class="">THB</div><div class="">HRK</div><div class="">EUR</div><div class="">MYR</div><div class="">NOK</div><div class="">CNY</div><div class="">BGN</div><div class="">PHP</div><div class="">PLN</div><div class="">ZAR</div><div class="">CAD</div><div class="">ISK</div><div class="">BRL</div><div class="">RON</div><div class="">NZD</div><div class="">TRY</div><div class="">JPY</div><div class="">RUB</div><div class="">KRW</div><div class="active">USD</div><div class="">AUD</div><div class="">HUF</div><div class="">SEK</div></div>
```

Comment: Но ведь это реализация на гридах. Разве это свойство доступно только для grid?

Comment: Какое именно? Такую задачу как по мне проще выполнить на гридах, у `flex` есть вроде только `gap`, и у него плохая поддержка.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: Для флекса тоже добавили поддержку свойств column-gap и row-gap http://joxi.ru/Vm6Ly4zivNWbaA
Либо это работает плохо, либо я что-то упустил в своей реализации. Тем не менее, ваш вариант с гридом мне нравится гораздо больше

Comment: Ну да, не нужно рассчитывать ширину блоков) И да, если вам оказался полезен ответ - нажмите стрелочку вверх, и если он решает проблему - галочку.

Comment: Я пытался, но рейтинг я пока поднимать не могу. Галочку поставил. Спасибо.